# Which datasheet CTR value to use in optocoupler circuit?

Tags: opto-isolator

I am looking to use the FODM8801C in my circuit: https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/fodm8801a-d.pdf

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2foUswc.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

"Vout" node goes into an IC with the following requirements:

- Vlow < 0.4V
- Vhigh > 2.1V
- Max leakage current out of the pin: 8uA

I've chosen the 36k resistor because it provides margin to the 0.4V low threshold when leakage current is taken into account:
8uA * 36k = ~0.29V

Saturation current through Q1 will be:
(12V-0.4V)/36k = 0.32mA

Forward current through D1 is 4.5mA, so the required CTR is
0.32/4.5 = ~7%

When calculating my CTR margin I am confused as to which CTR value I should be taking from the datasheet.
I don't understand what the saturated CTR value means - shouldn't it effectively be 0 since the current is determined by R1 only?

Should I be using the saturated CTR at Vce=0.4V or the linear CTR at Vce=5V?

[image]

Comment: Is you load IC TTL or 74HCT CMOS?  Your configuration won't work with TTL

Comment: The load IC is a hotswap controller LT4363 that accepts inputs up to 100V

Comment: This is a question about optimum SNR in logic where DC leakage worst case is treated as noise. And CTR is. Gain parameter sorted by bin in part number. Signal is your input current x gain and thresholds determine SNR for Opto leakage, load current, stray Crosstalk and noise currents degrading SNR. The error probability depends on SNR and unknown EMI from supply or radiated, can you verify 8uA and redefine your specs in terms of error margin, given most logic has a huge Margin that is defined by impedance ratios (source/interference) x current to threshold.

Comment: Saturated CTR means when Vce<1V the hFE begins to reduces towards the rated value at 400mV so nonsaturated hFE will not apply at say 500mV, it must be Vce>1 to ensure it is linear

Comment: As a rule you should design for the worse case. If then the best case has issues then either 1) use a CTR binned part or 2) use a better regulation or even some kind of feedback

Comment: Your temperature environment also affects CTR and this is not specified .  A common emitter approach may be better. To avoid the leakage concerns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, can your IC withstand ~12V on the input? I ask because those are TTL levels and its rare to have a chip that has that capability (outside of LDOs and similar special purpose devices).

The "saturated CTR" is the ratio of the specified output current to the current through the LED required to lower Vce to 400mV. At least that would be my assumption. So for the B bin you would need 1mA/.45 or 2.2mA. The unsaturated CTR is applicable in this case since you don't need Vce to drop to 400mV.

You should also account for temperature extremes and for aging, which might be another 2:1 or 3:1 depending on the LED quality and what temperatures you need to account for.

Your 8uA maximum dark current is also rather optimistic, 40uA or 50uA might be a safer number to use for Vce = 11.6V.

[image]

Comment: Wouldn't the saturation CTR be circuit-dependent then? Because the amount of current required to bring Vce down to 0.4V varies with the series resistance.

Comment: The transistor sees mA and yields voltage. The external resistance doesn't really matter.  For example, 1mA from a 0.8V source with 400 ohms in series will look the same to the transistor at 400mV as a 20.4V source with 20K in series.

Comment: Could you expand on the 1ma/45 calculation? I was under the impression If = 1mA referred to the LED current. So a CTR of 45% would yield Ic = .001*.45 = 0.45mA

Comment: @user2828776 That is a mistake. I'll edit. multiply  by 100. Gak. 2.2mA * 45/100 = 1mA.

Comment: Sorry, still not understanding the math. Shouldn't it be the other way around? The collector current should be 45% of the 1mA LED current?

Comment: 45% CTR means that an LED current of 1mA results in a phototransistor current of 0.45mA. So you need 2.2mA of LED current to get Ic of 1.0mA.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120863/discussion-between-user2828776-and-spehro-pefhany).